# What is the technical term in econometrics for when an independent variable is perfectly captured in the dependent variable?

Tags: regression, econometrics

I have forgotten the name of this term.

If I were to create a regression model in which one of the independent variables perfectly i.e regressing y ~ y(t-1), which would imply a causality issue, what is the name for this error?

Comment: the question is not clear enough. What is y? What is y(t-1)? What is t?

Comment: In econometrics, time is usually discrete. $t$ is conventional notation for time and so $t-1$ means previous time.